# Reloading objects from database, not cache, after stored procedure updates database?

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate to access an Oracle database.

I think I am having some trouble with Hibernate's first-level (or session) cache. I have tables representing accounts: the ACCOUNT table, the INVOICE table, and the PAYMENTS table. 
There are procedures defined in the Oracle database so that adding a PAYMENT will automatically update columns in the associated INVOICE and ACCOUNT tables.

The problem I have is when I use Hibernate to do something like the following:

```
Account account = accountDao.get(accountId);
assertEquals(0.00, account.getBalance());

// Saving a payment will trigger stored procedures that 
// will update the account balance.
paymentDao.save(createPaymentForAccount(accountId, 20.00));

account = accountDao.get(accountId);
assertEquals(20.00, account.getBalance());
```

The final assertion will fail because `account.getBalance()` returns `0.00` rather than `20.00`.

I want the second call to `accountDao.get(...)` to hit the database, and get the new ACCOUNT object back. But Hibernate appears to return the account object already in its cache (when I inspect the debug output for the lookup call, I see `number of objects hydrated: 0`).

I assume that Hibernate is unaware that the database has changed because of the stored procedure call, which is why it uses the object in its cache.

So I began thinking about solutions. One is to remove any ACCOUNT and PAYMENT objects from the hibernate session cache whenever a PAYMENT is saved. This will force a database fetch (with the newly updated values) for any ACCOUNT or INVOICE operation.

I tried the following:

```
public void save(Payment payment) {
  getSession().persist(payment);
  getSessionFactory().evict(Invoice.class);
  getSessionFactory().evict(Account.class);
}
```

But the hibernate trace log showed that nothing happened. I think that `sessionFactory.evict(...)` operates on the second-level cache, which is not enabled and so there's nothing to evict.

Next I tried evicting all ACCOUNT and INVOICE objects from the session cache by evicting each instance I could find:

```
public void save(Payment payment) {
  getSession().persist(payment);
  for (Invoice invoice: lookupInvoices()) { // e.g. "from Invoice" query
    getSession().evict(invoice);
  }
  for (Account account: lookupAccounts()) { // e.g. "from Account" query
    getSession().evict(account);
  }
}
```

This seems to work, but is horribly inefficient, because it loads all instances into the hibernate session cache before evicting them, when all I really want to do is evict any current instances in the session.

I cannot see any way of clearing the first-level cache of all objects of a specified type, so what other solutions are available?

Answer (score 13):

You can use session.refresh() method. See [11.3. Loading an object](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-loading) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that `refresh()` is the solution here, however. My understanding is that `refresh()` is useful for reloading an object that is updated by the database, e.g. if I save a `payment`, then `refresh` it if triggers modify its state. But in my case I need to call `refresh` on each existing ACCOUNT and INVOICE object in the cache when a PAYMENT is updated. How do I fetch each and every ACCOUNT and PAYMENT object from the cache?

Comment: You can set `cascade="refresh"` on these associations. In that case whenever an entity is refreshed, all associated entities will be refreshed too.

Comment: I can set `cascade="refresh"`, as you suggest, and because of associations between ACCOUNT and INVOICE this means that I only need to refresh the ACCOUNT objects. But the problem I need to solve is: how to get ACCOUNT objects from the cache so I can call `refresh` on each of them, without performing a `from Account` query? e.g. something like `getSession().refresh(Account.class)` (which does not exist in the API AFAIK, but that's the kind of functionality I am seeking).

Comment: I don't think refreshing entities one by one is a good idea. After all what refresh will do is to issue a separate query for each entity. Reloading those objects in one query seems better to me. Maybe, in your application, you can limit the number the accounts to be reloaded ?

Comment: I can't find a way access the entities in the session, too. And the reason is clear, i think. You are expected to have a hold to your entities.

Comment: Hmmm, yes. I can do something like `refresh(getInvoice(payment.getInvoiceId()))`, etc. However I also have a view that uses the ACCOUNT balance column, and I would still need to `refresh` any view instances in the cache.

Comment: I've modified my code to perform a lookup of associated objects, then refresh those objects, to handle this case. It's not ideal, because the lookup may put more objects into the cache than existed previously, but it seems to work. I'll mark the answer above as accepted, but with the caveat that there's some work required to find the set of objects to refresh, and this work may lead to ineffeciencies.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just evict the account object before reading it again from the database ? I would do this:

```
Account account = accountDao.get(accountId);
assertEquals(0.00, account.getBalance());

// Saving a payment will trigger stored procedures that 
// will update the account balance.
paymentDao.save(createPaymentForAccount(accountId, 20.00));

accountDao.getSession().evict(account)
account = accountDao.get(accountId);
assertEquals(20.00, account.getBalance());
```

Also you have to make sure your are not in a REPEATABLE_READ isolation level. In this isolation mode, Spring guarantees that two reads within the same transaction will always return the same result. As the isolation level takes precedence on your cache eviction, the cache evict will not have any visible effect.

There is a ways to work around this behavior:
Declare your transaction isolation level to READ_UNCOMMITTED or READ_COMMITTED. You might run into the famous "Standard JPA does not support custom isolation levels" exception if you are using a standard dialect. In which case you can apply the following workaround: 
spring 3.3:http://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/supporting-custom-isolation-levels-with-jpa/
spring 3.2:http://shahzad-mughal.blogspot.com/2012/04/spring-jpa-hibernate-support-for-custom.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm no longer working on that project anymore (or at that company) so I don't have a way of verifying your proposed solution. I did try evicting all Account classes in my original post, but evicting the instance is probably the way to go.